# Execution Time: Boost Multi-precision vs Java BigInteger

Tags: java, c++, boost, primes, biginteger

I'm trying to Implement the Lucas–Lehmer primality test.

I've two implementations, one in C++ and other in Java, These are follows:

C++:

```
int p = 86243;
cpp_int M;

bit_set(M, p);
M = M-1; // M = 2^p - 1;

cpp_int S;
S = 4;

while(p>2) {
         S = pow(S, 2);
         S -= 2;

         S %= M;
         p--;         
}
```

Java:

```
int p = 86243;

BigInteger M = BigInteger.ZERO;
BigInteger Two = BigInteger.valueOf(2L);

M = M.setBit(p);
M = M.subtract(BigInteger.ONE); // M = 2^p - 1;

BigInteger S = BigInteger.valueOf(4L);

while(p>2) {
         S = S.pow(2).subtract(Two).mod(M);
         p--;        
}
```

The Java code runs much faster than C++ code, for C++ I'm using CodeBlocks and Eclipse for Java.

Any reason for that? Am I missing anything particularly in C++ code? 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations turned on (release build)?

Comment: "much faster" is vague. Can you quantify? If yes, how do you quantify? Anyway, here is a part of the answer: those are different languages

Comment: Writing a micro benchmark in Java is non-trivial, see [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/1602555). You definitely shouldn't benchmark this from IDE.

Comment: Much faster means Java completed the execution one third of time than c++.

Comment: I didn't check the optimizations, I will. @ NathanOliver.

Comment: In C++ difference of executing speed of optimized and non optimized code is very significant, so it is quite pointless to measure speed of non optimized code.

Comment: Later versions of Java use advanced algorithms for multiplication and division that perform substantially better than the usual O(n*n) algorithms that are normally used for cryptographic-sized numbers and below. For comparison, GMP also uses these advanced algorithms and would represent a better challenger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should not expect both programs (Java and C++ versions) to be equivalent. The performance depends mostly on the algorithms used rather than the language. Running the C++ version in a profiler shows that the divide (i.e. mod) is the bottle-neck. If you then look at the source of the divide (/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int/divide.hpp) you can see this comment:

> Very simple, fairly braindead long division.
>   [...]
>   Note that there are more efficient algorithms than this
>   available, in particular see Knuth Vol 2.  However for small
>   numbers of limbs this generally outperforms the alternatives
>   and avoids the normalisation step which would require extra storage.

The BigInteger implementation in Java however uses algorithms called Knuth and/or BurnikelZiegler. Seems like these are better suited for larger numbers. If performance really matters you can try to use the gnu multi-precision library (gmp). On my machine the gmp version is roughly 3x faster than Java/BigInteger:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gmp.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int p = 86243;
    mpz_t M;
    mpz_init(M);
    mpz_set_ui(M, 0);
    mpz_setbit(M, p);
    mpz_sub_ui(M, M, 1); // M = 2^p - 1;

    mpz_t S;
    mpz_init(S);
    mpz_set_ui(S, 4);

    while(p > 2) {
        mpz_pow_ui(S, S, 2);
        mpz_sub_ui(S, S, 2);

        mpz_mod(S, S, M);

        p--;
    }
    int r = mpz_get_ui(S);
    cout << "Is mersenne prime: " << (r == 0 ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Link with -lgmp

Answer (score 3):

You can check the comparison by using inbuilt clock function available. Here is the comparison of this C++ and Java code

C++ -> https://ideone.com/oj07xQ

Java -> https://ideone.com/MsAgil

You can see C++ is taking 1933.19 milliseconds while Java is taking 2257.244454 milliseconds

You can not compare speed on different IDE's like CodeBlocks and Eclipse

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;
using namespace std;

int32_t main() {
    int start = clock();
    int p = 8624;
    cpp_int M;
    bit_set(M, p);
    M = M-1; // M = 2^p - 1;
    cpp_int S;
    S = 4;
    while(p>2) {
             S = pow(S, 2);
             S -= 2;

             S %= M;
             p--;         
    }
    // cout << S << endl;
    int end = clock();
    cout << "time: " << (end - start)/(double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000 << " milliseconds\n";
}
```

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int p = 8624;
        BigInteger M = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger Two = BigInteger.valueOf(2L);

        M = M.setBit(p);
        M = M.subtract(BigInteger.ONE); // M = 2^p - 1;

        BigInteger S = BigInteger.valueOf(4L);

        while(p>2) {
                 S = S.pow(2).subtract(Two).mod(M);
                 p--;        
        }
        // System.out.println(S);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Took "+(endTime - startTime) + " ns"); 

    }
}
```

Comment: *You can not compare speed on different IDE's like CodeBlocks and Eclipse* Why not, we do it all of the time.  You just need to make sure your compiling with the same/equivalent settings.

Comment: Also note that most likely IDEOne is not using the same compiler either for C++ and Java.

Comment: For smaller input (for p) both programs behaves almost same in my machine as well, I am interested only larger values of p, in million range. Where C++ runs very slow (3 to 4 times slower) compared with Java program. @Aman Raj.

Comment: I tried and run it and largest value I can run on my system was P = 10000. Even at this number C++ is working faster than Java. Take a look at this [cpp_int](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html)  and [BigInteger](https://coderanch.com/t/588080/java/BigInteger-Peformance) . As the number is larger and larger both will try to take exponential time. @Manoj Banik